# Automatic monitoring of HTTP resources

Tags: java, http, monitoring

I'm building a Java application that gathers information from a lot of sources using HTTP. I'm looking for a framework that could help me track which resources are online, are not responding or are responding with error codes. Preferrably that also can detect when resources come online again.

This is to avoid polling servers that are not responding correctly. Does anyone know if there is such a framework? I haven't found anything approriate. Lightweight options would be great.

Comment: How should those tools work? They'd have to poll the servers anyways (there's normally no broadcast when resources go offline or come online again).

Comment: I was thinking that when I execute a get request and getting a bad response/no response, notify the framework, if I get X number of such responses in X seconds, mark it as offline and don't retry until X seconds has passed (or if there is some automatic polling detecting it). It's a little vague for me also, but I think someone must have done this before me. :)

Answer (score 0):

For working with HTTP in Java in general, I can recommend the [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) library by Apache. It has a good documentation and is easy to use.

Use the [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) class' [execute(...)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) method to easily find out whether a resource is online or not. You can find the status code by inspecting the [status line](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine%28%29) of the response.

EDIT: If you use this library, you will have to hand-code the specific aspects of your problem: Repeated polling of resources and some sort of event-based informing when resources go down or come up again.

However, I think this can be done quite quickly, for example by using a timer. This way, you don't have to include an additional framework. The HTTPClient library is rather lightweight, although that depends of course on your definition of the word. Note that it comes with dependencies to HTTPCore, commons-logging and commons-codec.

Comment: Thx for your input, yes you are probably right it would not take to long to code this myself, Iäll look into it if no other options come up here!

Comment: Seems like there is no such framework out there yet. After all, it is **kind of** a specific problem. But if you're going to implement this, you can change the situation! ;-)

Comment: You are right, I will take it upon myself to add this magical library to the world!